# Method of type loaded by reflection is not being called

Tags: c#, plugins, reflection, asp.net-web-api

I am seeing some weird behaviour with a "plugin" system I am developing for an ASP.NET Web API project. The plugins are DLLs which are copied into the bin folder. This means they are already in the current AppDomain.

Each plugin has a configuration class which implements IPluginConfiguration.

The following class configures the plugins by finding all of the classes in the current AppDomain which implement the IPluginConfiguration interface. This is called from Global.asax.cs

```
public class PluginConfigurator
{
    /* ... */

    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var pluginConfigs = GetPluginConfigurations();

        try
        {
            foreach (var pluginConfigType in pluginConfigs)
            {
                var pluginConfig = (IPluginConfiguration) Activator.CreateInstance(pluginConfigType);
                pluginConfig.Configure(config);
                Logger.Log("Configured Type: {0}", pluginConfigType.FullName);
            }
        }
        catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException e)
        {
            Logger.Log("Error of type: {0}", e.GetType().Name);
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Type> GetPluginConfigurations()
    {
        return  AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                                .GetAssemblies()
                                .SelectMany(t => t.GetTypes())
                                .Where(type => !type.IsInterface)
                                .Where(type => typeof(IPluginConfiguration).IsAssignableFrom(type));
    }
}
```

My test plugin has the following config.

```
public class PluginConfiguration : IPluginConfiguration
{
    /* ... */

    public void Configure(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        try
        {
            Logger.Log("Configuring test plugin");
            RegisterRoutes(config);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Log("Error of type {0} in configuration", e.GetType().Name);
        }
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

So I would expect my log file to say either

```
Configuring test plugin
Configured Type: MyNameSpace.PluginConfiguration
```

or

```
Configuring test plugin
Error of type MyNameSpace.PluginConfiguration in configuration
Configured Type: MyNameSpace.PluginConfiguration
```

But actually I just get

```
Configured Type: MyNameSpace.PluginConfiguration
```

There is other logging that occurs before this. I thought it could be a problem with the logging, so I made it create a file instead in the PluginConfiguration class, which it also didn't do. It appears that my PluginConfiguration class isn't being called.

I created a unit test calling the PluginConfigurator class and the method does get called.

Any suggestions of what could be causing this or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The code works for me (ie. I see both logging messages) when I stick it into the `Application_Start()` of the web app I'm working on and load a secondary DLL from the **bin** folder.

The first thing I would do to reassure yourself the method really is being called is explicitly throw an exception in your `Configure()`.  In that case you should see the "Error of type:" string.  (Perhaps throw a custom string in your exception to be absolutely sure.)

Once you're sure it's being called you can start working on the logging problem.  My best guess, having tried and failed with desperation logging strategies before, would be permissions.  Since this is presumably a web app, write permissions are going to be pretty restricted.  You could also be running into [ASP.NET's shadow copy](http://www.ipreferjim.com/2012/04/asp-net-appdomains-and-shadow-copying/) and simply not finding the logfile.

In any case, you are probably *not* running into a mysterious called-but-not-called situation due to the reflection.  It is most likely a more mundane problem.

The second thing I would do is forget trying to make a custom plugin system and use [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead, heh.